# What can replace “consists of”?

Tags: synonyms, formality, phrasal-verbs, register, tech-writing

For reasons I cannot explain, I hate the phrase *consists of*. Does anyone have an alternative? An example is:

> Testing **consists of** continual operation, alternating between random writes and random reads.

To me, that phrase just sounds pompous.  As a technical writer for international audiences, I try to keep my words as simple as possible.

Comment: how about "comprise"? From merriam-webster.com: com·prise
verb \kəm-ˈprīz\: to be made up of (something) : to include or consist of (something): to make up or form (something)

Comment: @MattGutting That was my first thought, too—but then if ‘consists of’ is considered too pompous-sounding, I’d hate to think how ‘comprises’ would fare.

Comment: *Consists of* is plenty fine; otherwise see the treasure-book’s **General Reference** suggestions for
*[comprises](http://thesaurus.com/browse/comprise),
[covers](http://thesaurus.com/browse/cover),
[includes](http://thesaurus.com/browse/include),
[involves](http://thesaurus.com/browse/involve),
[entails](http://thesaurus.com/browse/entail),
[consists of](http://thesaurus.com/browse/consist%20of),
[is composed of](http://thesaurus.com/browse/be%20composed%20of),
[is made up of](http://thesaurus.com/browse/be%20made%20up%20of),
[takes in](http://thesaurus.com/browse/comprehend),* and many more.

Answer (score 1):

Example sentence:

- Our picnic **consists of** sandwiches and lemonade.

Alternatives:

- Our picnic **comprises** sandwiches and lemonade. (Edited- thanks Scott)
- Our picnic **contains** sandwiches and lemonade.
- **The components of** our picnic **include** sandwiches and lemonade.

Comment: I would use comprise. +1

Comment: But it should be “Our picnic **comprises** sandwiches and lemonade.”

Comment: We will picnic/are picknicking on sandwiches and lemonade.

Answer (score 1):

There are all sorts of alternatives:

- Testing **is**  XX hours of continual operation ...

or

- Testing **subjects** each unit to XX hours of ...

or

- Testing **requires** each unit to perform  ...

or, if there is more than one test:

- Testing **is**  in four parts:

  1. XX hours of ...

Or if you're really tired of thinking up verbs:

- **Testing:** xx hours of ...

Comment: I am not sure that: "Testing is XX hours of continual operation" works here. Testing entails, calls for, or means.

Comment: @Lambie Depends on what *testing* signifies. If it signifies the action of completing all the required tests, you're right; but if it's the name of a phase of the workflow, *is* works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

> Testing consists of continual operation, alternating between random
>   writes and random reads.

edited:

- Testing ***entails*** continual operation, alternating between random writes and random reads.

As in this text:

> Why Test Automation is Critical to Continuous Testing
>   To fully understand why test automation is so critical to continuous testing, it’s important to make clear what exactly continuous testing entails and why it came about.
>
> [entails](https://medium.com/qasymphony/test-automation-vs-automated-testing-the-difference-matters-f3ef5fc132de)

- Testing ***means*** continual operation, alternating between random writes and random reads.

As in this text:

> On the contrary, distributed testing means that a test consists of several parts and each of them is performed on a separate computer.
>
> However, the term “distributed” means not only a simultaneous run of tests on a number of machines, which is specific for parallel testing.
>
> [means](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/advanced/distributed/basic-concepts.html)

- Testing ***calls for*** continual operation, alternating between random writes and random reads.

As in this text:

> And how we should shift left requirements engineering and design to address the damaging impact of defects and rework stemming from ambiguous or incomplete requirements. More specifically, Paul cites that this new model for testing calls for “attempting to identify the distinct thought processes involved in exploring sources of knowledge and the system under test and to scope, design and select meaningful and valuable tests of systems.”
>
> [calls for](https://www.ca.com/en/blog-agile-requirements-dhttps://www.ca.com/en/blog-agile-requirements-designer/the-new-model-for-testing-in-the-modern-software-factory.htmlesigner/the-new-model-for-testing-in-the-modern-software-factory.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Involves**

Testing involves continual operation, alternating between random writes and random reads.

https://www.yourdictionary.com/involves

**Is concerned with**

Testing is concerned with continual operation, alternating between random writes and random reads.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concerned%20with

**Denotes**

Testing denotes continual operation, alternating between random writes and random reads.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/denote

Answer (score 0):

It is a little hard to see without the wider context but what about:

- 'Testing requires continual operation...'
- 'Testing is achieved through continual operation...'
- 'Testing is managed by continual
  operation...'

Comment: Hi Margaret, welcome to EL&U. Good suggestions (although *achieved* was already proposed by another answer), but it's too short: the system will inevitably flag it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's best if you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., why do these alternatives work well, and ideally published examples of their use. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)